# How to reenable full access to a drive's folders and files in windows 10?

Tags: windows

At my PC with `Windows 10`, I wanted to experiment (unfortunately!) with the `accessibility` of the entire disk (not fortunately the main one) and through `properties/security/advanced/Edit/type:Deny` I made its contents (folders and files) inaccessible.

When I tried to restore the original state with the reverse process (`type:allow`) I got many error messages

`An error occurred...`

`the filename`

`Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Acces is denied`

and at the end for each folder it asks me again to change permissions with errors and in general I have lost access to most folders and files.

Can someone guide me to restore full access to all the contents of the disk

PS I swear I will never try such dangerous tricks again!

Comment: oh my god, have you asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)? also, have you tried to [take the ownership using administrative account](https://superuser.com/a/813881)?

Comment: Just one tip: When I want to do such experiments, I always use a virtual disk. When using a differencing VHD I can also go back to the status I have saved before.